# Getting Trouble in Placing files in variable Folder in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, boto3

I am downloading files from s3 bucket and I want to place them in their respective folders.

```
with open(wrkbk, 'r') as csvfile:
    datareader = csv.reader(csvfile)
for row in datareader:
    stage, path = row[0],row[1]
    fpath  = os.path.join("C://Users//local1//Project101//Images//",stage)
    your_bucket.download_file(path,fpath+path)
```

What I want is the images go to

```
**Images->Stage-1->image1.jpg
        Stage-2-> image2.jpg**
         .
         .
```

but what is happening is this.

```
Images-> Stage-1image1.jpg, Stage-2image2.jpg
```

I have already all the stage folder made inside the Image folder, so I didn't try the *os.makedir()*

it is not going inside the seperate folder. I tried doing fpath/path, but its saying string can't be divided.

and they are not going inside the folder, instead, the name is sticking along with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use `os.path.join()` for the last segment too, so there's a slash in-between.

I also added `os.path.basename()`, just in case the CSV file's `path` also has a directory part...

```
base = "C:/Users/local1/Project101/Images"

with open(wrkbk) as csvfile:
    datareader = csv.reader(csvfile)

    for stage, path in datareader:
        filename = os.path.basename(path)
        full_path = os.path.join(base, stage, filename)
        your_bucket.download_file(path,full_path)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks soo much, This piece of code works with ease, i didn't knew about the os.path.basename.
You reduced my 150 line of code to 20 lines :->

Answer (score 2):

The function below downloads all files of a bucket path, to a local directory.
The indication the path is a file - when it does not ends with "/"
It will create the recursive directories of the root local directory you download to

```
import boto3
import os
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

def download_s3_folder(bucket_name, s3_folder, local_dir=None):
    bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket_name)
    for obj in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=s3_folder):
        if obj.key[-1] == '/':
            continue
        target = os.path.join(local_dir, os.path.relpath(obj.key, s3_folder))
        if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(target)):
            os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(target))
        print(f"downloading {obj.key} to {target}")
        bucket.download_file(obj.key, target)
```

Usage example

```
download_s3_folder("MY_BUCKET", "PATH/Images/", "./Images")
```

Would download all content from path `PATH/Images/` from `MY_BUCKET` bucket to the current working directory you running the script from at directory `./Images` and will keep the files/paths structure

In order to download all of the bucket content while keeping the files/paths structure use -

```
download_s3_folder("MY_BUCKET", "", "./my-bucket-content")
```